# Mongo C# driver - API BsonDocument.Add to include raw data...like decimal, boolean etc

Tags: c#, mongodb

```
BsonDocument doc = new BsonDocument(false);
object rawValue = GetVal();
doc.Add(somename, rawValue.ToBsonDocument()); //This works fine but fails when I use just rawValue
```

Any help regarding how I can pass the raw value without using `.ToBsonDocument()`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BsonValue` doesn't have implicit type conversion for `object`. Try to update `GetVal` for receiving generic type instead of `object`.

Comment: Ok, that would be a lot of if-else for handling various data types. I was thinking there could be some API on mongo driver to handle the GetType() part on object.